# Making mathematica solve a complicated system

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following system:
$$ d^2 = at^6 + bt^2 + c \\e^2 = a(t + 1)^6 + b(t + 1)^2 + c \\f^2 = a(t + 2)^6 + b(t + 2)^2 + c$$

I'm trying to solve for a, b, and c in terms of the other variables.

If I naively try to solve this system:

```
Solve[{d^2 == a*t^6 + b*t^2 + c, e^2 == a (t + 1)^6 + b (t + 1)^2 + c,
   f^2 == a (t + 2)^6 + b (t + 2)^2 + c}, a]
```

It just returns an empty list. The actual solution is pretty complicated, but it's nothing that Mathematica can't handle:
[image]

How can I make Mathematica solve this system?

Comment: The empty list means that there is no solution.  Your system is overdetermined: one variable and three equations.  Mathematica's response is correct.  If a, b and c are all variables (and not parameters), specify that. Then you have a different system.

Comment: Otherwise use the option `MaxExtraConditions -> All`. The Mathematica will give you the conditions on the parameters under which there is a solution for `a`.

Comment: Have you looked in the documentation?  The second "basic example" shows you how to solve systems of equations.  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html  EDIT: This was a response to a now deleted comment about how to specify variables.

Answer (score 5):

The correct code is:

```
sol = Solve[{d^2 == a*t^6 + b*t^2 + c, e^2 == a (t + 1)^6 + b (t + 1)^2 + c,
   f^2 == a (t + 2)^6 + b (t + 2)^2 + c}, {a, b, c}]
```

You have to solve it with respect to `a,b,c`, not only `a`.

Maybe you were interested only in `a`, in that case you can do something on the line of:

```
A1 = a/.sol
```